# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime - when string format is different from system datetime format

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, datagridview

My system short date time format is d/M/yyyy. I'm passing "03/29/2011 02:38:18 PM", so it is giving error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

```
DateTime.Parse("03/29/2011 02:38:18 PM")
```

If date time format of machine is set to m/d/yyyy, it works perfectly.

**Edit:**
My application is a winform application, it contains a data gridview, this grid view contains a custom DateTime control (columns), which is created by other developer. 
This error is occurring when I try to change value of this datetime column in grid. VS debugger is not catching the exception, so I'm not able to find location where I should try fixing it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to the format `d/M/yyyy`, `03/29/2011` would amount to month number 29 that does obviously not exist.

The other format has day and month switched, and the string then represents 29. March which is a perfectly valid date.

Comment: I know,but there is should be a way to handle this.

Comment: @Sharique - The way to handle it is using ParseExact. There you can give both the string to Parse **and** the format. This is the solution, given that the string always contain the date and time in the same format I have to add.

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx):

> Important Because the Parse(String)
>   method tries to parse the string
>   representation of a date and time
>   using the formatting rules of the
>   current culture, trying to parse a
>   particular string across different
>   cultures can either fail or return
>   different results. If a specific date
>   and time format will be parsed across
>   different locales, use the
>   DateTime.Parse(String,
>   IFormatProvider) method or one of the
>   overloads of the ParseExact method and
>   provide a format specifier.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, well, the DateTime.Parse function  uses the system format to parse the date, unless you provide a FormatProvider. Obviously in case of d/m/yyyy there is no month 29 so the parsing fails

Answer (score 0):

Use [DateTime.ParseExact()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) instead.  You can specify exactly how to parse the date if you know what the string looks like going into the function by passing in the correct [FormatString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx).  If the standard DateTime Format Strings don't work, you can use a [custom DateTime Format String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime.ParseExact` to parse datetime from string

Example:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("2001-01-01", "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change the culture information, so your input matches the format of the system.

So try to add this in the web.config:

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="en-US" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer here: [String was not recognized as a valid DateTime " format dd/MM/yyyy"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193012/string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime-format-dd-mm-yyyy)

You can parse the Date with a corresponding CultureInfo, which defines the date format and the order of the date parts (Month,Day,Year) or (Day,Month,Year).

Or you could use the ParseExact and give it a format string as described in the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

See "[convert Different formate of DateTime to specific String format in c#](http://forums.asp.net/t/1851868.aspx/2/10?convert%20Different%20formate%20of%20DateTime%20to%20specific%20String%20format%20in%20c%20)"

```
private DateTime ConvertToDateTime(string strDateTime)
{
DateTime dtFinaldate; string sDateTime;
try { dtFinaldate = Convert.ToDateTime(strDateTime); }
catch (Exception e)
{
string[] sDate = strDateTime.Split('/');
sDateTime = sDate[1] + '/' + sDate[0] + '/' + sDate[2];
dtFinaldate = Convert.ToDateTime(sDateTime);
}
return dtFinaldate;
}
```