# Convert string to datetime in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

this is my input to a text box from a datetime calendar
 and to store the datetime in the DB i want the value to be changed to Date time.

```
DateTime Res_date = Convert.ToDateTime(txt_RespondBy.Text);
```

when I convert it gives a error saying string not recognised as valid date time. How to convert the input to date time..

value of txt_RespondBy.Text is : 10/27/2011 03:25

Comment: What's the value of `txt_RespondBy.Text`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193012/string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime-format-dd-mm-yyyy/2193037#2193037

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use DateTime.Parse, see MSDN: [DateTime.Parse Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx)

```
string[] dateStrings = {"2008-05-01T07:34:42-5:00", 
                        "2008-05-01 7:34:42Z", 
                        "Thu, 01 May 2008 07:34:42 GMT"};
foreach (string dateString in dateStrings)
{
   DateTime convertedDate = DateTime.Parse(dateString);
   Console.WriteLine("Converted {0} to {1} time {2}.", 
                     dateString, 
                     convertedDate.Kind.ToString(), 
                     convertedDate);
}
```

There is Also [ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) where you can specify the pattern string you are using....

Answer (score 2):

Use DateTime.TryParseExact to avoid exceptions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) with the correct format string.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [DateTime.Pares](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) or [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

What is the format of the string you're trying to parse? Anyway, take a look at DateTime.ParseExact(): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx

It allows you to provide a format in which the date is represented.