# Insert the date into table

Tags: asp.net, string, datetime, insert, calendar

I am trying to get From date and To date in two text boxes using the calender control and then trying to insert this value in a table. How can I proceed with this??
Please help..

```
string comstr = "insert into ATM_DETAILS_TB values(" + txtpin.Text + ",'" + Convert.ToDateTime(txtvldfrm.Text) + "','" + Convert.ToDateTime(txtvldto.Text) + "'," + Convert.ToInt32(ddlaccno.SelectedValue) + ",'" + Session["strUid"].ToString() + "')";
```

while using this code it shows error like "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

what should I do??

Answer (score 2):

1. Use [Validation controls to validate that the values in textbox values are valid dates](http://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2009/02/aspnet-rangevalidator-how-to-validate.html).
2. Your code us contencating strings directly from user input.  This opens you up to all sorts of nasty attacks, the primary being SQL Injection.  [Use parameterized queries instead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx#paght000002_step3).

Answer (score 1):

Always use `DateTime.TryParse` or `TryParseExact` method to parse the date.

```
DateTime vldDate;
bool isValid=false;
if(DateTime.TryParse(txtvldfrm.Text,out vldDate))
 {
    isValid=true;
 }
....
if(isValid)
{
  command.Parametter.Add("@vldto",SqlDbType.DateTime).Value=vldDate;
  command.Parametter.Add("@strUid",SqlDbType.VarChar,30).Value=Session["strUid"];
  ..... 
}
```

Comment: Hello AVD, thanks for ur reply. how to add parameter for Session["strUid"].ToString() using command.Parametter.Add()? Please help

Answer (score 0):

You Use from parameterized queries like this:

```
 string comstr = "insert into ATM_DETAILS_TB values(@pin,@vldfrm,@vldto,@ddlaccno,@strUid)";

    YourCommand.Parametter.AddWithValue("@vldto",Convert.ToDateTime(txtvldto.Text));
    YourCommand.Parametter.AddWithValue("@strUid",Session["strUid"].ToString());
    ....Define the Other Paraametter
```

Edit----
check this question [*String was not rec...*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193012/String)

Comment: That won't help with the error he's seeing, but I agree 100% that he should be using parameterized queries.

Comment: hi mtaboy, thanks for ur help. I tried the same way u told me.But it shows the same error like
""String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"Please help.

Comment: hi raji. what is your Date column type in your table?

Comment: hi,  i created table as below:create table ATM_DETAILS_TB(PK_ATM_DETAILS_ATMID numeric identity(1234,1) primary key,PIN numeric,VALID_FROM datetime,VALID_TO datetime,FK_ATM_DETAILS_USER_ACC_ACCNO numeric references USER_ACC_TB(PK_USER_ACC_ACCNO),FK_ATM_DETAILS_STAFF_USERID varchar(20) references STAFF_TB(PK_STAFF_USERID))

Comment: are you sure that your date input text is a valid date?and i suggest you a link in my answer