# String not recognized as valid datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, formatexception, datetime-parsing

My code gives the above error.

I have tried to change it based on the link below:

[String was not recognized as a valid DateTime “ format dd/MM/yyyy”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2193037/1270384)

but it still does not work.

Would be grateful if somebody can point me in the right direction.

My code is below:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)

        {

       // int RowIndex = 0;
       // GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[RowIndex];

            Int32 intresortID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["TypeID"]);
            Label dtm = row.FindControl("Label1") as Label;
            Label strRoomType = row.FindControl("Label2") as Label;
            Label strDescription = row.FindControl("Label3") as Label;
            TextBox Qty = row.FindControl("intQtyTextBox") as TextBox;
            TextBox Price = row.FindControl("curPriceTextBox") as TextBox;
            Label intWSCode = row.FindControl("intWSCodeLabel") as Label;

            string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["bestandConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(connStr))
            {
                Con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update tblAvail set intqty=@intQty, curprice=@curprice where intresortid=@intresortid and dtm=@dtm and strroomtype=@strroomtype", Con);
```

> cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtm",
>   DateTime.ParseExact(dtm.Text.Trim(), "dd / MM / yyyy",null));
>   Line giving the error

```
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strroomtype", strRoomType.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@intQty", Qty.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@curPrice", Price.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@intResortID", intresortID);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
                DataBind();

            }
```

In design Mode:

```
  <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Eval("Dtm", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
  </ItemTemplate>
```

When debugging dtm value comes as:

> {Text = "18/05/2012"}

Comment: Can you debug the method and see how the date value is coming in and post it in your question?

Comment: Try to use the SqlDateTime.Parse instead of DateTime.ParseExact

Comment: I get the error saying SQLDatetime does not exist in this current context

Comment: Scorpion-Prince amended question with value above.

Comment: Can you convert first string to date, and after that try retrieve in specific format?

Comment: you mean like this?                                             DateTime dm;
dm = Convert.ToDateTime(dtm.Text);

Comment: Seems a little odd that you convert the datetime to a string in the label and then try to convert it back to a datetime instead of just using the original value?

Comment: @James Manning: Would you please help me improve my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dtm.Text.Trim(), "dd/M/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

<sub>four y instead of 3 and InvariantCulture</sub>

Comment: That was a typo error, apologies . Have amended my code to show the correct way. it still gives error.

Comment: @user1270384: i also edited my answer and added `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`

Comment: no luck...still gives same error. When I mouse over in debug mode reads as dtm.text ={"18/5/2012"}

Comment: @user1270384: It would work with `18/05/2012`. Why is the zero omitted in the month? Try to use this format instead: `dd/M/yyyy` (edited my answer)

Comment: I've confirmed in LINQPad that Tim's answer (DateTime.ParseExact with "dd/M/yyyy") works fine with both month values in the string of 5 and 05