# date format issue, String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting dates from database and i want to convert the date in dd/MM/yyyy format,

I am trying this but it gives me error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

```
DateTime pDate = DateTime.ParseExact("05/28/2013 12:00:00 AM", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Please let me know how i can convert into dd/MM/yyyy format?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193012/string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime-format-dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: By switching the "05" and the "28"?

Comment: yes, date can be '12/31/2013 12:00:00' or any thing else with this format.

Comment: Think about what `.ParseExact` does in comparsion to `.Parse`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx  ...as in, are you sure you want the 'exact' variety?

Comment: why don't you just add CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [yourdate], 103) AS [DD/MM/YYYY] to your SQL ?  It's the datetime format for dd/MM/yyyy.

Comment: yes i should try this. sorry i didn't think like this. i will do like this.

Comment: @AltafSami What is the database server and data type of your date column and how you read data? can you update the question with those information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 steps:

```
DateTime pDate = DateTime.ParseExact("05/28/2013 12:00:00 AM", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);


return pDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: This will fail because You have AM, PM in the given string

Comment: you are right. I did not check msdn for the standard date format token that take care of am/pm. The idea still stands: 2 steps. And depending on the quality or the diversification of the text data of date, you may design a structure to try a few date format string before giving up.

Answer (score 6):

try with `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt` instead of `dd/MM/yyyy`

if you use `DateTime.ParseExact` **The format of the string representation must match a specified format exactly** or an exception is thrown.

if you need only the date

```
DateTime pDate = DateTime.ParseExact("05/28/2013 12:00:00 AM", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var dateOnly= pDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

---

As per your comment, database contain data with Type 'Date',  So you can read it directly as `DateTime`. You can convert to string by calling `ToString` with the expected Format.

Comment: this also gives same error. actually time is also with date when i fetch from db, i want only date.

Comment: @AltafSami If you fetch the date from the database, why are you using a string? You could put it directly in a date variable.

Comment: @AltafSami what is the dataType of date column in your data table?

Answer (score -1):

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Parse( 
   "15/12/2019",
   new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR"));
```

refer https://blog.submain.com/string-was-not-recognized-as-valid-datetime/