# Error in parsing string into datetimepicker

Tags: c#, .net

I have a column in my database with dates stored as string in the following format:

- 2/6/2018
- 5/9/2018

In my winform, I am using a `DataGridView`, which is linked to a `DataSet`.

On a cell_click event I want to extract the string from the respective column in the datagridview (studentstudentbirthdateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn) and parse it into a DateTimePicker element.

This is my code:

```
string dateTimeString = row.Cells["studentstudentbirthdateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString();
dateStudentBirthdate.Value = DateTime.ParseExact("dd/MM/yyyy", dateTimeString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

However, when I initiate the event I get the following error:

```
String was not recognized as a valid `DateTime`.
```

Any clues what is it that I am getting wrong?

Comment: Your format string and datetime string are swapped.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a String to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-a-string-to-datetime)

Comment: Another duplicate [date format issue, String was not recognized as a valid DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797912/date-format-issue-string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime)

Comment: By the way, this should teach you that you should **never ever** use text fields to store dates. Use either date types or number, to store Unix timestamps

Comment: If the DGV column's datatype is DateTime, most of the code us not needed.  You cant cast column value to DT and since the DTP Value property is `DateTime` no heroics needed to assign it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment:

> Yes, but the data can also contain double digit days. 20/05/2016 for example.

`DateTime.ParseExact` have one more overload `ParseExact(String, String[], IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles)` which will allow you to provide multiple parse formats. For example:

```
string dateString = "2/6/2018"; //or "20/05/2016"
string[] formats = { "d/M/yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy" };
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

**[Fiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Vpm7BU)**

Answer (score 1):

your sample data contain 1 digit for day and 1 for month, where as on your parse format you specify to digits for each. Try:

```
 DateTime.ParseExact("d/M/yyyy",
                     dateTimeString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Yes, but the data can also contain double digit days. 20/05/2016 for example.

Answer (score 0):

The soluton is simple.. don't use ParseExact:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse("2/6/2018");
```