# How to append datetime value to formdata and receive it in controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime, form-data

I want to know how I can pass datetime value through formdata and
retrieve it in controller and convert it to DateTime in the controller

I've tried as below:

```
var formdata=new FormData();
fromDate = $('.from_date').datepicker('getUTCDate');
toDate = $('.to_date').datepicker('getUTCDate');

formdata.append("start", new Date(fromDate));
formdata.append("end", new Date(toDate));
```

and in `$.ajax` I am setting `data:formdata`

in my controller I receive it as below:

```
DateTime frmDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form["start"]).Date;
DateTime toDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form["end"]).Date;
```

But here I get a `System.FormatException` while trying to `Convert` to datetime and when I keep a watch for `Request.Form["start"]` then the value will be `"Fri Mar 30 2015 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (Indian Standard Time)"` but it considers it as string when retrieving from request.

**Is it possible to pass datetime type through `Request`?**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You get FormatException because the date string is not formatted in recognized pattern for the .NET date parser. If we can be more specific about the format in javascript we can satisfy the .NET parser.

```
var datestr = (new Date(fromDate)).toUTCString();
formdata.append("start", datestr);
```

Either of these will give us an accepted format

- [toUTCString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString)
- [toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

Now we parse the string in your server-side code

```
DateTime fromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form["start"]).Date;
```

Depending on your machine's culture settings you may need to use `DateTime.ParseExact()` instead of `Convert.ToDateTime()`.

**Is it possible to pass datetime type through Request?**

Along the pipeline from javascript to your controller action this will be converted to a string or integer anyway. We could return the tick (milisecond) representation for the DateTime but then you'd need to convert that to .NET ticks which uses a different epoch and nanosecond units.

Just stick to strings with standard formats.

More on parsing Date formats [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193012/string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime-format-dd-mm-yyyy).

Comment: nice one.. I'll implement this tomorrow and will let you know. Similarly any idea on passing model to controller through formdata?

Comment: Upvote for your effort and I feel this should work but then let me implement and let you know..

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use formdata? As opposed to plain objects or json.

Comment: Yea @jasen.. I need to pass an image file uploaded by user and I find this is the only way with the approach I follow and I am appending it to formdata.

Comment: That would probably be best posted as a separate question. Others would find it easier to find and more useful.

Comment: The second question you are talking about?

Comment: Yes, the passing formdata to controller as a model.

Comment: Sure. I'll edit the question and post it as separate one by tomorrow. Right now time to sleep. It's too late here.. :)