# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime when string is 13/07/15

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a string `date = 13/07/15` in this format and I want to convert it into DateTime, but I get the error mentioned below

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

What can I do to convert into datetime. I have tried this

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
```

Comment: Show how are you converting it to `DateTime`

Comment: possible duplicate of [String was not recognized as a valid DateTime " format dd/MM/yyyy"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193012/string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime-format-dd-mm-yyyy)

Comment: Does the culture on the server accept dates in the format `dd/MM/yyyy`?

Comment: `DateTime` probably expects a string in "dd/mm/yy hour:min" so either add the time to your string to make it a valid `DateTime` or format it according to your needs.

Comment: When you use that overload, the string is parsed with the current culture of the current thread. We do not know what that culture is? You can specify a culture where you know the parse will succeed, for example `Convert.ToDateTime("13/07/15", new CultureInfo("en-GB"))` since British culture allows this "little-endian" order with slashes as separators. It also works with `"fa-IR"` (which means Persian/Farsi in Iran). It does not work with `"en-US"` or `""` cultures; they want the month first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code `DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);` is perfect. Seems to me like the error is in your database, because it converts it into date if it gets the full year. Please check it in your database.

Answer (score 1):

Never noticed that different cultures write their data and time in different formats? Although the format you use is valid in most Western European countries it is rubbish in the United States.

To overcome this problem, you can ask the system for the current date and time format:

```
var currentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfor.CurrentCulture
IFormatProvider dateTimeFormat = currentCulture.DateTimeFormat;
string dateTxt = @"13/7/2015";
System.DateTime myDate = System.DateTime.Parse(dateTxt, dateTimeFormat);
```

That should do the trick if your computer has the correct culture.

If you want to be able to understand a lot of cultures, don't ask for the current culture but use one of the constructors of System.Globalization.CultureInfo

> Not wise, because does 1/3/2015 mean March 1st, or January 3rd?

Answer (score 0):

Do like this,

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "dd/MM/yy", null);
```

Source : [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx)