# Convert String to Date Time C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, datetime

I'm new to c# how can I convert my input string in to DateTime.

```
_toDate = 5/22/2015
```

I cannt use

```
DateTime.ParseExact(_toDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", null);
```

Or

```
Convert.ToDateTime(_toDate)
```

throw an exception **String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.**

Note : String shold be excact the same as above.

Appreciate your reply

Comment: `yyyy-MM-dd` does not seem to match your date.

Comment: possible duplicate of [String was not recognized as a valid DateTime " format dd/MM/yyyy"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193012/string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime-format-dd-mm-yyyy)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Clearly, your string and format does not match.

From [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.ParseExact.aspx);

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent. The format of the string representation must
>   match a specified format **exactly**.

You need to use `M/dd/yyyy` with a culture that has `/` as a [`DateSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator.aspx) like [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) .

```
string _toDate = "5/22/2015";
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(_toDate, "M/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

When you use `null` as an `IFormatProvider`, it's threaded as your `CurrentCulture` and if your `CurrentCulture` doesn't have `/` as a `DateSeparator`, you will get `FormatException` because [`/` custom format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#dateSeparator) has a special meaning as *replace me with current culture or supplied culture date separator*.

Comment: That works for the specific case given, but it's more likely the OP needs to use `M/d/yyyy`.  It's unlikely the format being used would zero pad the day, but not the month.  Also I'm not the down voter.

Comment: @juharr That works for the specific case because it is the _only_ case we have. You have a point, `d` specifier parses it as well but since OP try to parse it with `dd` specifier, there is a chance that single day numbers _may_ have leading zeros.