# string is not able to convert to date time in the given query

Tags: c#

I have a `string` and when I try to convert that to a `DateTime` it's throwing an error. Why?

```
string str = "3‎/‎23‎/‎2016‎ ‎5‎:‎10‎:‎32‎ ‎PM";
datetime= convert.ToDateTime(str);
```

Comment: Use `DateTime.Parse`

Comment: Either add a leading "0" before your month or use DateTime.Parse

Comment: Well, reading the error message (that you don't want to show us?) will give you a hint. You probably need to define the culture to use for parsing.

Comment: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.Parse id again throwing error" String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"  ;  DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(str);

Comment: @BWA according to msdn `Convert.ToDateTime` uses `DateTime.Parse`, so that won't help.

Comment: you are missing leading 0 of hour

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String was not recognized as a valid DateTime " format dd/MM/yyyy"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193012/string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime-format-dd-mm-yyyy)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a String to DateTime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-a-string-to-datetime)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, and `Convert.ToDateTime` should work fine if his culture has that format. The problem is quite different.

Comment: Please check before saying that , its duplicate :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Convert.ToDateTime` should work fine if your current culture allows this.

You however have some strange characters in your string... I have copied and pasted it and it didn't work, however writing it directly did.

Check it in a fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/l5nzso

It seems you have some [left-to-right mark (0x200E)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm) Unicode characters scattered between the characters in your string. Check it [in this other fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/goe3dG)

Comment: I just noticed the same thing.  The length shows as 32 instead of 20.

Comment: It seems there are some [left-to-right mark (0x200E)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm) unicode characters scattered in the string, pretty weird

Comment: The left-to-right mark characters could be replaced to make this work `str = str.Replace(new string((char)8206, 1), string.Empty);`

Comment: @Jcl , Awesome findings, how can I remove those  Unicode characters.

Comment: @juharr gave you the solution right in the comment above yours