# Why is this DateTime.ParseExact statement not working?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

The following line gives me a "String was not recognized by a valid DateTime" error:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("4/6/2016", "dd/MM/yyyy", Nothing)
```

I got this "working" example on stackoverflow, but it doesn't work for me: [Parse Exact Sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2193037/1539292) and I can't figure out why.

EDIT (reedit, I mistakenly typed the last two attempts wrong):
Still no good.  This is what I've found after trying all the suggestions submitted so far (thanks all).  Some more info, the date string is coming from a textbox control.

```
Dim xxx As String = "4/6/2016"  'OR  = "04/06/2016" as necessary for the sample
```

This does not work:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(xxx, "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

This does not work:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(xxx, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

After, I tried something simpler with just DateTime.Parse:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(xxx)
```

I typed this out by hand. I did NOT use values from a textbox control and it DID work:

```
DateTime.Parse("4/6/‎2016‎")
```

So frustrating

Comment: Maybe if you try this way: `DateTime.ParseExact("04/06/2016", "dd/MM/yyyy", Nothing)` .....

Comment: conclusion: the value in your textbox is not what you typed out by hand - use the debugger to see exactly what value is being used. Are you sure it is M/d/yyyy and not d/M/yyyy for example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your format says you'll have two digits for the day and the month. Your actual values only have one digit.

You have two options:

- Follow the format you've specified, e.g. `04/06/2016`
- Change the format to match the value, e.g. `d/M/yyyy`

Additionally - and separately - you're passing in `Nothing` as the format provider, which means the current culture will be used. Your format uses `/` which is the culture-specific date separator. If your current culture doesn't use `/` as its date separator, that's another problem. If you've got a fixed format, you probably want to specify `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as the format specifier instead.

Here's a short but complete program demonstrating it working:

```
Option Strict On

Imports System
Imports System.Globalization

Public Class Test

    Shared Sub Main()
        Dim xxx As String = "4/6/2016"
        Dim result as DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(xxx, "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        Console.WriteLine(result)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: @CarlosMendieta: `DateTime.ParseExact(xxx, "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` works fine for me. What *exactly* do you mean by "doesn't work"? Ideally, show a [mcve] demonstrating the problem. It sounds like maybe your text box doesn't actually have the string you think it does...

Comment: @CarlosMendieta: I've now included a short but complete program simply copying and pasting bits of code that you claimed don't work, and putting them in a `Main` method. It works fine. It sounds like what isn't working for you *isn't* what you've shown.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `dd` or `MM` it expects a two digit number, so you would need to use `"04/06/2016"` or else replace them with their single digit versions of `d` and `M`.