# How to remove two characters and replace from a string in the middle in c#

Tags: c#, string

I have a string like this **25/05/2016** now I want to get a string like this
**25/05/16** and like this **25-05-2016**  how can I do this in c#.

Comment: Is the source string *always* in this format DD/MM/YYYY? If so you can convert the source into a `DateTime` and then format it into any representation you like.

Comment: sry for the confused, it is like DD/MM/YYYY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always just use string manipulation:

```
var source = "25/05/2016";
var result1 = String.Join("/", source.Split('/').Select(x => x.Substring(x.Length - 2, 2)));
var result2 = source.Replace("/", "-");
```

These give the correct results:

```
25/05/16
25-05-2016
```

Answer (score 16):

Instead of string manipulation, parse the Date properly:

```
var date = DateTime.Parse("25/05/2016");

var date1 = date.ToString("dd/MM/yy");   <-- 25/05/16
var date2 = date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"); <-- 25-05-2016
```

Comment: I got  a small problem here `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.` in first line

Comment: @bill - You need to make sure that you're using the right globalization culture for parsing.

Comment: k, thanx by the way and found the answer

Answer (score 0):

Nitin's answer is the best for your problem.

But if it were not an date you could convert the String to an byte array, modify the characters you need to and then convert it back to string.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I did

```
 string s = "25/05/2016";

 var date = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "dd/MM/yyyy",null);
 var date1 = date.ToString("dd/MM/yy");
 var date2 = date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

helped log @Nitin's answer and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193012/string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime-format-dd-mm-yyyy)  stackoverflow questiong