# ToDateTime only works when I pass in the string

Tags: c#

When I try this:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(newReg.dob)
```

I get the following error:

> 'Convert.ToDateTime(newReg.dob)' threw an exception of type
>   'System.FormatException'

However, when I do:

```
Convert.ToDateTime("3/3/2000")
```

It results in the following:

> {3/3/2000 12:00:00 AM}

newReg.dob is a string "3/3/2000" - what is the difference?  How do I get this to work?

**What I'm seeing locally:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you *sure* it contains that? Testing locally does not throw an error.

Comment: Put a line right above that to log it somewhere... you'll find it's not what you think it is.

Comment: You need a [mcve] that clearly demonstrates this issue otherwise we can't help.

Comment: @Enigmativity - Will my screenshots help?

Comment: @Hogan - it was typo on my part.  The same results occur even when I type Convert.ToDateTime("3/3/2000")

Comment: Is `dob` of type `string`? Assign it to a string and then convert that string. If that fails, then make that string be "3/3/2000". If it workes, then you have to see what's the difference between `dob` and that string. I guarantee you: there is something. BTW, making your method return a string containing "error" is a code smell to me. You should handle errors in a better way.

Comment: what type is newReg.dob?

Comment: @Hogan - string

Comment: Are both of your tests running in the same environment? Meaning, is it possible that the test is running under one, possibly the default CultureInfo, while the throwing code has the current thread's Culture set to something else?

Comment: @Andrew - I assigned newReg.dob to a string and then tried to Convert.ToDateTime(myDOBString) and received the same error - the code you are looking at is very early in dev.  I'm going to change.

Comment: can you show the code context -- is it part of a closure or something like that?

Comment: Also, is it possible that your `dob` string has invisible, non-printing characters, like a UTF-8 BOM? Compare the string's `Length` property with the character count you expect (8)

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan - That may be it.  newReg.dob.Length = 13 and it only should contain 8 characters?  How can I fix that?

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/q/2193012/5395773

Comment: @webdad3 - No, screenshots will only confirm what you're saying. You need code that we can run that replicates the error.

Comment: @Enigmativity - I guess I didn't know what was happening myself and didn't know until after someone suggested the hidden characters.  This one was gong to be difficult to replicate in code.  I'll keep that in mind though for next time.

Comment: @webdad3 - The process of replicating this in code often leads to an answer along the way - or even simply a better question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better use `DateTime.TryParseExact` as below,

```
DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(newReg.dob.Trim(), "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
   myPerson.personDOB =date;
}
else
{
   // Parse failed
}
```

By using above you can specify Culture invariant date time parse and also you can identify cases where this conversion failed, without exception.

in case of you have unwanted characters in the input string, you can use regex to get the content you want, or write simple code to filter unwanted content like below

```
string input ="$3/3/2000#$@#$ter ";
var outstring= new string(input.Where(c=>char.IsDigit(c)|| c=='/').ToArray()); //you get 3/3/2000 as result
// now you can pass this to above DateTime.TryParseExact method
```

Comment: At best, this would be a workaround for this exact string. At worst, as is apparently the case, it won't work because the real issue is that the string contains invisible characters.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan I haven't see the discussion on comments section until I post this answer. updated my answer. Thanks

Comment: After I removed the extra characters from my string as you suggested above all options started to work!