# string with Persian Calendar format was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, persian-calendar

I use Persian Date (Iranian Date Format or Jalali Calendar) in my program.

and when i use this:

```
string A = "1396/2/30";
string Test = String.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", Convert.ToDateTime(A));
```

I get the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   but was not handled in user code. Additional information: String was
>   not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String was not recognized as a valid DateTime " format dd/MM/yyyy"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193012/string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime-format-dd-mm-yyyy)

Comment: What is your `CurrentCulture` exactly? Be aware, you don't use _any_ calendar in your code.

Comment: As well as the accepted answer, I'd encourage you to consider using my Noda Time project (http://nodatime.org) which has what I'd consider to be rather clearer support for separate calendars than the BCL does. (For example, even after parsing, the `DateTime` will "forget" that it was parsed from the Persian calendar value...)

Answer (score 3):

Create a fa-IR `CultureInfo` and then try using `DataTime.ParseExact()` instead of `Convert.ToDateTime()`.

**Update**

```
var persianCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("fa-IR");
persianCultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = new PersianCalendar();
string dateString = "1396/02/30";
DateTime MyDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyy/MM/dd", persianCultureInfo);
```

Comment: It did not work and again:

"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

"Damet Garm Vali Nashod :("

Comment: Try changing `DataTimeFormat` calendar to a new instance of `PersianCalndar`. Updated answer will work without problem.

Comment: New error: "Not a valid calendar for the given culture."

Comment: I tested this code and it worked fine. Are you sure you are referencing `System.Globalization.PersianCalendar` and you haven't imported any other calendar named `PersianCalendar` from other namespaces?

Comment: It seems `PersianCalendar` can not be as the default calendar for a culture in .NET Framework 3.5 or any earlier versions of .NET. Change your target framework to .NET 4 or above to solve this issue.

Comment: I use "ArashPersianCalendar" in WPF and my .NET Framework is 4.5!!