# Why this string is not a date

Tags: c#

I do not understand where I'm making the mistake that gives me this error `System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime'`

UserDOB work correctly, but DateTimeStamp not.

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    list1.Add(new User()
    {
        UserId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["UserId"]),
        UserName = reader["UserName"].ToString(),
        UserSurname = reader["UserSurname"].ToString(),
        UserPassportNo = reader["UserPassportNo"].ToString(),
        UserAccessPoint = reader["UserAccessPoint"].ToString(),
        UserAccessType = reader["UserAccessType"].ToString(),
        UserDOB = DateTime.Parse(reader["UserDOB"].ToString()),
        DateTimeStamp = DateTime.Parse(reader["DateTimeStamp"].ToString()),
    });
}
```

My model.DatabaseConnection

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string UserSurname { get; set; }
    public string UserPassportNo { get; set; }
    public string UserAccessPoint { get; set; }
    public string UserAccessType { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime UserDOB { get; set; }

    //[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public System.DateTime DateTimeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: most likely the data is null.

Comment: what does the string look like? can you provide an example?

Comment: Unless you give us the string you're trying to parse, there's nothing we can do to help.

Comment: Don't use `ToString` and then force your code to convert a string *back* into a `DateTime`. Use `DateTime` datatypes throughout your code. Converting everything into strings *introduces* the opportunity for problems

Comment: 1. Check if the value is `System.DBNull.Value`, you can use [reader.IsDBNull](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull(v=vs.110).aspx) 2) Hopefully the table schema's column type for `UserDOB` is `Date` or `DateTime` or `DateTime2` in which case you should use [reader.GetDateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdatetime(v=vs.110).aspx). This is assuming it is Sql Server you are querying.

Comment: use reader["DateTimeStamp"].ToString() as reader["DateTimeStamp"]?.ToString() this might resolve your problem and type of your DateTimeStamp should be DataTime?

Comment: possible duplicate of this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193012/string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime-format-dd-mm-yyyy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you store date as a string in DB. This varchar doesn´t meet format to parse it to **DateTime**. Change your SQL query to DB so it returns your DateTimeStamp as a correct format (yyyy-MM-dd) or convert it to DateTime with SQL before you read it from code.

Also when you use DataReader try to look at `reader.GetDateTime(reader.getordinal("DateTimeStamp"))` function.