# How to convert datetime exactly what I am getting the output from client side

Tags: c#

I have a variable as property like this:

```
DateTime? something;
something  = Convert.ToDateTime(d1);
```

where `d1 = '04/20/2020 12:50 PM';`

I get a runtime error:

> String was not recognized as a valid `datetime`

Then I tried this code:

```
something  = DateTime.TryParseExact(d1, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm tt", null);
```

and get a compile time error:

> No overload for method 'TryParseExact' takes 3 arguments

Then I tried to convert it like by below too

```
something  = DateTime.TryParseExact(d1, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime dt);
```

and got another compile-time error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `bool` to `System.DateTime?`

How to convert `nullable datetime` to getting `datetime` format?

[image]

Comment: See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String was not recognized as a valid DateTime " format dd/MM/yyyy"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193012/string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime-format-dd-mm-yyyy)

Comment: @Hamid Reza Mohammadi its not working...saying 3 parametrised methode not available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct use of `TryParseExact`

```cs
public static void Main()
{
    string d1 = "04/20/2020 12:50 PM";

    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(d1, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm tt", 
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime dt));

        Console.WriteLine("Date time OK: " + dt);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Date time: " + d1);
}
```

Comment: how could save it in  db then?

Comment: @abbasahmed There is nothing in your question about saving to DB. But you can do this as Hamid Reza shows - `DateTime dbVal? = null; if (tryparse(....)) dbVal = dt;` 3 Lines of code and now your `dbVal` is ready for saving

Comment: I updated with image please check it, getting that error after I updated as u mentioned.

Comment: Just remove that whole `system.codedom` section. Do you compile your code manually?

Comment: @abbasahmed What does it mean "as usual". ? How do you run your app? Remove from config file in your app. Probably web.config

Comment: @abbasahmed great. Find web.config in your app and remove this setting

Comment: Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'AppThereCRM_V2.MvcApplication'.

Source Error:
Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="AppThereCRM_V2.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>

Comment: @abbasahmed right-click on your solution and click `Rebuild`. Or do same in the build menu

Comment: Also check [this](https://forums.asp.net/t/2119455.aspx?Error+when+running+a+localhost+site)

Answer (score 2):

See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.8)

```
public static bool TryParseExact (string s, string format, IFormatProvider provider, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles style, out DateTime result);
```

> Parameters
>
> s String A string containing a date and time to convert.
>
> format String The required format of s.
>
> provider IFormatProvider An object that supplies culture-specific
>   formatting information about s.
>
> style DateTimeStyles A bitwise combination of one or more enumeration
>   values that indicate the permitted format of s.
>
> result
>   DateTime When this method returns, contains the DateTime value
>   equivalent to the date and time contained in s, if the conversion
>   succeeded, or MinValue if the conversion failed. The conversion fails
>   if either the s or format parameter is null, is an empty string, or
>   does not contain a date and time that correspond to the pattern
>   specified in format. This parameter is passed uninitialized.
>
> Returns Boolean true if s was converted successfully; otherwise,
>   false.
>
> Exceptions ArgumentException styles is not a valid DateTimeStyles
>   value.
>
> -or-
>
> styles contains an invalid combination of DateTimeStyles values (for
>   example, both AssumeLocal and AssumeUniversal).

So we need to check the success or fail, and handle it.

```
DateTime? something;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(d1, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime dt))
    something = dt;
else
    something = null;
```

Comment: 2 lines too long

Comment: @Hamid Reza Mohammadi I updated with image, getting error

Comment: Errors resolved but what i want that not getting..as per 04/20/2020 12:50 PM this format in if getting false..
in dt getting 01-01-0001 00:00:00

Comment: @abbas ahmed `DateTime` is struct and have a default value. so if this method failed the `result` parameter value is {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}. You must handle success or fail of this function as your needs.

Answer (score 1):

TryParseExact return a bool, yout datetime object is dt

```
public static void Main()
    {
        string d1 = "04/20/2020 12:50 PM";

        var result  = DateTime.TryParseExact(d1, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime dt);

        Console.WriteLine(dt);

    }
```

Comment: Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: The CodeDom provider type "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" could not be located.