# How to Convert Stringified Date Value in format Month/Day/Year Time as a DateTime?

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I've got a class that contains two DateTime members.

When I try to assign a "human-readable" value representing a date to the DateTime member, though, it rejects it with the message, "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

The line of code that fails is:

```
md.BeginDate = DateTime.Parse(reader.GetValue(5).ToString());
```

In context, showing the value that I am trying to convert from a string representation of a DateTime:

[image]

Based on the 1st and accepted answer here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193012/string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime-format-dd-mm-yyyy], I also tried this:

```
md.BeginDate = DateTime.ParseExact(reader.GetValue(6).ToString(), "MM/dd/yyyy", null);
```

...but with the same ignominious result.

### UPDATE

Based on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-5.0), I tried the following:

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff";
. . .
DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
```

...but get the same result.

The value of "dateValAsStr" is *2021-01-21 11:25:56.9608384*

### UPDATE 2

It turns out it was a really dumb oversight on my part. When I stepped through it, I saw that the Date (TEXT) value in the database was empty. So this code "works" (doesn't throw an exception):

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff";
. . .
string qry = "SELECT LocationName, Address1, City, StateOrSo, PostalCode, " +
                        "BeginDate, EndDate, MapDetailNotes, Latitude, Longitude " +
                        "FROM CartographerDetail " +
                        "WHERE FKMapName = @FKMapName";
. . .
dateValAsStr = reader.GetValue(5).ToString().Trim();
if (! String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dateValAsStr))
{
    md.BeginDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateValAsStr, format, provider).Date;
}
dateValAsStr = reader.GetValue(6).ToString().Trim();
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dateValAsStr))
{
    md.EndDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateValAsStr, format, provider).Date;
}
```

Comment: Try `"MM/dd/yyyy"` instead of `"mm/dd/yyyy"`. You didn't capitalise the M's. Lowercase `m` is minutes and uppercase `M` is months.

Comment: What's the type of the column you're retrieving? If it's already a date/time in the database, use `md.BeginDate = reader.GetDateTime(5);` Converting to a string and then parsing it is asking for trouble. Avoid the format issue entirely.

Comment: It's SQLite, which doesn't have a Date data type. The MapDetails C# class, OTOH, does declare it as public DateTime BeginDate { get; set; }

Comment: @Enigmativity: Still get the same err msg with capitalized Ms

Comment: If I remember correctly, SQLite [advises storing dates in ISO-8601 format](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). If the database does not follow that convention, please show sample data.

Comment: @madreflection: The data in the table's TEXT column is of the format "2021-01-05 06:54:36.4256254"

Comment: Alright, so it follows the convention. Notwithstanding the fact that it's a different format than the answer showed, how did the answer you linked not help? I don't see a call to `DateTime.ParseExact` in your code.

Comment: @madreflection: ParseExact is at the bottom of my question

Comment: Having looked at the format of the dates in the database, can you see now what you should pass for the format to `DateTime.ParseExact`?

Comment: @madreflection: Good tip; I'm guessing yyyy-MM-dd, but don't know if I can ignore the time part. I hope so. I'll give it a try...

Comment: @madreflection: Nope, still get same err msg with md.BeginDate = DateTime.ParseExact(reader.GetValue(6).ToString(), "yyyy/MM/dd", null);

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: Parse it *with* the time part (including *all 7* `f` places...you only have 6 there), and then take the `Date` property of the result to remove the time part.

Comment: @madreflection: Beautiful - after adding the additional "f" this works: md.BeginDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateValAsStr, format, provider).Date; Make it an answer, and I will accept it as such.

Comment: You don't need ParseExact, Parse is sufficient: `var date = DateTime.Parse("2021-01-21 11:25:56.9608384", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`;

Comment: I still get the same err msg with that

Answer (score 4):

The simple example you give is this:

```
string dateString = "2021-01-21 11:25:56.9608384";
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff";
DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
```

Note that the number of decimal places for the seconds is `7`, yet your `format` only has `6` `f`s.

If you change to `7` `f`s then it works fine.

Comment: I started with six, and was told I needed 7; and there are seven in the example (9608384)

Comment: @B.ClayShannon - Yes, but you only have 6 `f`s - you need 7 of those.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right, there were only 6 there; there were 7 in the code, as now shown in Update 2.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon - Is `UPDATE 2` the answer to your question?

Comment: Yes, it is an amalgamation of various comments/answers here.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon - Then please post as an answer to the question and delete it from the question itself. Then you can mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: If the number of decimal places could vary in your input, you should use `FFFFFFF` (7 capital `F` characters) which will correctly parse input with anywhere from 0 to 7 decimal places.  Otherwise, this answer looks good.  See also the chart [on this docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/types).

Comment: @Enigmativity: I want to award the bounty to somebody.

Answer (score 3):

If you have time where the Millisecond size has inconsistent length, try this method that I use to one system we have that deliver such inconsistent time.

```
public static string DynamicMillisecondDateTimeFormat(string date)
{
    var size = date[(date.LastIndexOf(".", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1)..].Length;
    var fs = new string('f', size);
    return size == 19 ? "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" : $"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.{fs}";
}
```

To test this lets do following:

```
string[] dates = {
    "2021-01-21 11:25:56",
    "2021-01-21 11:25:56.9",
    "2021-01-21 11:25:56.96",
    "2021-01-21 11:25:56.960",
    "2021-01-21 11:25:56.9608",
    "2021-01-21 11:25:56.96083",
    "2021-01-21 11:25:56.960838",
    "2021-01-21 11:25:56.9608384"
};

var provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

foreach (var date in dates)
{
    var format = DynamicMillisecondDateTimeFormat(date);
    DateTime.TryParseExact(date, format, provider, DateTimeStyles.None, out var dateTime);
    Console.WriteLine(dateTime.ToString(format));
}
```

If we take that in your context, you can do some thing like:

```
var format = DynamicMillisecondDateTimeFormat(ReaderOptions.GetValue(5).ToString());
bool parsable = DateTime.TryParseExact(date, format, provider, DateTimeStyles.None, out var dateTime);
if (parsable)
{
    md.BeginDate = date;
}
```

Btw this [link](https://www.crystalnet-tech.com/RuntimeLibrary/Help/html/scr/Custom_Date_and_Time_Format_Strings.htm) has some interesting information about the date time formatting.

In addition thanks to @MattJohnson-Pint commented and made me aware of better alternative to my `DynamicMillisecondDateTimeFormat` method where you just need to do following format, it will automatically take all millisecond lengths between 0 to 7. note it should have capital Fs:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.FFFFFFF"
```

Comment: This is nice out-of-the-box thinking, but it is unnecessary.  Just use `FFFFFFF` (7 capital `F` characters).  It will correctly parse input with anywhere from 0 to 7 decimals.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint I have updated my question with it, I have also testing it. Nice very cool way. Enjoy your day and thanks again for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a new DateTime like this, by splitting the reader.GetValue(5) into the appropriate slot

```
int d1 = 200;
int d2 = 2;
int d3 = 24;
DateTime datet = new DateTime(d1,d2,d3);
md.BeginDate = datet;
```

The d1, d2, and d3 is what you will need to replace with the data split from getvalue

Comment: Thanks; I may have to resort to this "brute force" approach after all

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `Parse` instead.  There's a pretty good series of examples in the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=net-5.0)

```
(string dtStr, string descr)[]  dateInfo = { 
      ("08/18/2018 07:22:16", "String with a date and time component"),
      ("08/18/2018", "String with a date component only"),
      ("8/2018", "String with a month and year component only"),
      ("8/18", "String with a month and day component only"),
      ("07:22:16", "String with a time component only"),
      ("7 PM", "String with an hour and AM/PM designator only"),
      ("2018-08-18T07:22:16.0000000Z", "UTC string that conforms to ISO 8601"),
      ("2018-08-18T07:22:16.0000000-07:00", "Non-UTC string that conforms to ISO 8601"),
      ("Sat, 18 Aug 2018 07:22:16 GMT", "String that conforms to RFC 1123"),
      ("08/18/2018 07:22:16 -5:00", "String with date, time, and time zone information" ) };

Console.WriteLine($"Today is {DateTime.Now:d}\n");

foreach (var i in dateInfo) {
  Console.WriteLine($"'{i.dtStr}' = {DateTime.Parse(i.dtStr)} {i.descr+ ":",-52}");
}
```