# how to Calculate the differents between 2 system times with one from string

Tags: c#, datetime, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to calculate the amount of seconds between 2 times.
1 of the times values comes from my database in a string and I try to convert it to `System.DateTime` in Unity without success.

This is the string from the database: `3-5-2022 10:20:45`

```
public string starttime = "3-5-2022 10:20:45";

public void StakingProfitCheck()
{
    StartCoroutine(StakingCheck());
}

IEnumerator StakingCheck()
{
    WWW pwww = new WWW("DatabasePage");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);
    yield return pwww;
    starttime = pwww.text;
    Timecalculator();
}

void Timecalculator()
{
    System.TimeSpan ts = System.DateTime.UtcNow - Convert.ToDateTime(starttime);
    Debug.Log (ts.Seconds.ToString());
}
```

Giving this error:

> FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
> System.DateTimeParse.Parse (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] s,
> System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi,
> System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles styles) (at
> :0) System.DateTime.Parse
> (System.String s, System.IFormatProvider provider) (at
> :0) System.Convert.ToDateTime
> (System.String value) (at :0)
> StakingMenuScript.Timecalculator (System.String StartTime) (at
> Assets/Scripts/StakingMenuScript.cs:54)
> StakingMenuScript+d__5.MoveNext () (at
> Assets/Scripts/StakingMenuScript.cs:50)
> UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext
> (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr
> returnValueAddress) (at <13e6546058e340ada820e34dce3b245e>:0)

How can I calculate the time difference in seconds???

Comment: So, your immediate problem is parsing the string to a DateTime.

Comment: How do i solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String was not recognized as a valid DateTime " format dd/MM/yyyy"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193012/string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime-format-dd-mm-yyyy) Format is slightly different but should let you parse the datetime properly

Comment: @phuzi i edit the script in the question is this better?

Comment: maybe take a look at DateTimeFormatInfo: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is parsing the date not correct.

You can use `DateTime.Parse`. Assuming your format is german your code should look like this.

```
private void Timecalculator(string startTime)
{
    var start = DateTime.Parse(startTime, new CultureInfo("de-DE"), DateTimeStyles.None);
    var difference = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(start);
}
```

Comment: Do i have to add some libary at the top?? Im getting 2 error messages.

Assets\Scripts\StakingMenuScript.cs(56,47): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CultureInfo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Assets\Scripts\StakingMenuScript.cs(56,69): error CS0103: The name 'DateTimeStyles' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @MitchZ You have to add the namespace `using System.Globalization;`

Comment: Awesome, So im running into 1 more issue saying this:     
FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
System.DateTimeParse.Parse (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] s, System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles styles) (at <feaaa6313e32495d9f259b175aa6b597>:0)
System.DateTime.Parse (System.String s, System.IFormatProvider provider, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles styles) (at <feaaa6313e32495d9f259b175aa6b597>:0)
                            I use (System.DateTime.UtcNow).ToString() to upload to the server. if this info helps

Comment: With the sample string from your question or another? Please edit the question with additional info so it will be clearer. I tested it with the string from your question and had no errors.

Comment: `    private void Timecalculator(string startTime)
    {
    var start = DateTime.Parse(startTime, new CultureInfo("de-DE"), DateTimeStyles.None);
    var difference = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(start);
    Debug.Log(difference);
    }`
This is how i have the code now but it gives me the error from my previous answer

Comment: Like i just asked: what is the string you are calling the method with? ;) Without this info it is impossible to help you

Comment: "3-5-2022 10:20:45" Sorry man haha this is the string its also on the top of my code in the question

Comment: And you are getting the error in the method `Timecalculator`? Because I just used this method in a testproject with the same string and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Do you have discord or telegram so i can send you over screenshots. I think that wil will make this a lot easier

Comment: You can attach a screenshot in your question ;)

Comment: Image 1 & 2 are the code and 3 is the error message 
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQdI7.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zd0X.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vH99T.png

   I could update the poast so i sented it like this

Comment: I couldnt update the post

Comment: Can you please check the error code for me

Answer (score 0):

You parse date in inappropriate way. What you can try is to use `ParseExact` with `string` date format of your expectations.

```
var dateString = "3-5-2022 10:20:45";
var format = "d-M-yyyy HH:mm:ss";
var result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine("{0} converts to {1}.", dateString, result.ToString());
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-6.0

To get the time difference you can use this syntax:

`System.TimeSpan diff = secondDate.Subtract(firstDate);`